# react maps dependency issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am working on react native and installing

npm install react-native-maps

But i am getting error in react native cli as mentioned below

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'reactmaps'.

  > Could not read script 'E:\react\Projects\reactmaps\reactmaps\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' as it does not exist.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Settings file 'E:\react\Projects\android\settings.gradle' line: 2
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'reactmaps'.

  > Could not read script 'E:\react\Projects\reactmaps\reactmaps\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' as it does not exist.

As i installed react native cli again and again but still getting error. so what is the problem in this

Comment: Hi Punnet, it looks like you have not configure react-native environment. Please refer to https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started this documentation and setup for React Native CLI Quickstart guide.

Comment: My react project are working fine even i am also getting output and but when i install react-native-maps dependency then i am getting this error also setup android variable in environment varibales

Comment: * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-maps'.
> Could not get unknown property 'supportLibVersion' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Try to remove node_modules folder then run `npm install`